# PHP Emailer Fayal Error sheetNameExists()

Tags: php, excel

Having another fatal error.This one is a bit odd as I have the code fully functional on a different site, so I copied it and it's required files over. But whenever I run it I get a fatal error. Anyone know why?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel::sheetNameExists() in /home3/hutch/public_html/sulmaxcp.com/PHP/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php on line 835

```
<?php
    //Excel Transfer
    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Spo.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $spo = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Cont.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $cont = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Site.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $site = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Job.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $job = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/ObBrief.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $des1 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/ObAgreed.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $act1 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/ObDate.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $date1 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GoBrief.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $des2 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GoAgreed.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $act2 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GoDate.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $date2 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);    

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/FeBrief.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $des3 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/FeAgreed.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $act3 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/FeDate.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $date3 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);    

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Q1.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P1Radio1 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Q2.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P1Radio2 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);    

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Q3.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P1Radio3 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Q4.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P1Radio4 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Q5.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P1Radio5 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Q6.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P2Radio1 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Q7.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P2Radio2 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);    

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Q8.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P2Radio3 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Q9.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P2Radio4 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Q10.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P2Radio5 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Add.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $add = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);    

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Name.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $name = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);    

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Title.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $title = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);    

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Date.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $date = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    Include_once 'PHP/PHPExcel.php';

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Senior Managers Site Tour');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(5);

    $styleArray = array(
        'borders' => array(
            'allborders' => array(
                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
                )
            )
        );  

    //Set Up
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('E1','Senior Managers Site Tour');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:N70')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:A70');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('N1:N70');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B6:M68')->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);

    //Logo & Title
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B1:D4');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('E1:M4');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B5:M5');

    $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
    $objDrawing->setName('Murphys Logo');
    $objDrawing->setPath('IMAGES/LogoExcel.png');
    $objDrawing->setCoordinates('B1');
    $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

    $titleArray = array(
        'font'  => array(
            'bold'  => true,
            'size'  => 32,
        ));

    $styleTitleAlign = array(
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
        )
    );

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E1')->applyFromArray($titleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E1')->applyFromArray($styleTitleAlign);

    //Basic Information
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B6:D6');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('E6:G6');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('H6:J6');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('K6:M6');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B7:D7');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('E7:M7');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B8:D8');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('E8:M8');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B9:M10');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B6','Site / Project / Object:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('E6',$spo);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('H6','Contract Number:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('K6',$cont);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B7','Site Manager:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('E7',$site);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B8','Job / Task Description:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('E8',$job);

    //Observation
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B11:M11');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B12:E12');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F12:I12');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J12:M12');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B13:E17');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F13:I17');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J13:M17');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B18:M19');  

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B11','OBSERVATION (areas where improvement can be made).');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B12','Breif Description:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B13',$des1);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('F12','Agreed Action:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('F13',$act1);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('J12','Close Date:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('J13',$date1);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B11')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

    //Good Practices
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B20:M20');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B21:E21');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F21:I21');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J21:M21');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B22:E26');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F22:I26');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J22:M26');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B27:M28');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B20','GOOD PRACTICES (Commendable acts and actions, Improvements, Innovations etc).');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B21','Breif Description:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B22',$des2);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('F21','Agreed Action:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('F22',$act2);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('J21','Close Date:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('J22',$date2);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B20')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

    //Feedback Given & Received
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B29:M29');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B30:E30');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F30:I30');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J30:M30');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B31:E35');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F31:I35');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J31:M35');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B36:M37');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B29','FEEDBACK GIVEN & RECEIVED');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B30','Breif Description:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B31',$des3);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('F30','Agreed Action:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('F31',$act3);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('J30','Close Date:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('J31',$date3);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B29')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

    //General Impression
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B38:M38');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B39:G39');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('H39:M39');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B40:G40');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('H40:M40');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B41:M41');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B42:K42');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L42:M42');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B43:K43');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L43:M43');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B44:K44');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L44:M44');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B45:K45');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L45:M45');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B46:K46');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L46:M46');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B47:M47');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B48:K48');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L48:M48');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B49:K49');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L49:M49');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B50:K50');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L50:M50');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B51:K51');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L51:M51');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B52:K52');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L52:M52');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B53:M54');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B38','GENERAL IMPRESSION');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B39','1 = No evidence / poor / no understanding');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('H39','2 = Some evidence / understanding / not consistent');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B40','3 = Requirements in place / basic unerstanding');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('H40','4 = Detailed understanding / more than minimum standards');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B38')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B41','CULTURE');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B42','Is the CDP obvious - You Said / We Did Boards; Feedback Stations; Posters?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L42',$P1Radio1);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B43','Are there any Speak Up Coaches on this site?');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L43',$P1Radio2);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B44','Are Focus Leader meetings happening?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L44',$P1Radio3);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B45','Mention the Mental Tools, do people understand them?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L45',$P1Radio4);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B46','Ask what "Never Harm" means to the teams:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L46',$P1Radio5);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B41')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B47','SYSTEM');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B48','Are first impressions good, site signage, induction etc?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L48',$P2Radio1);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B49','Is the site tidy, well laid out etc?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L49',$P2Radio2);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B50','Are morning briefings / daily risk assessment carried out?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L50',$P2Radio3);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B51','Have all the team been briefed & signed onto the RAMS?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L51',$P2Radio4);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B52','Ask what they would do if there was a change in the work activity i.e. not in RAMS?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L52',$P2Radio5);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B47')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

    //Comments
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B55:M55');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B56:M63');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B64:M65');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B55','Additional Comments:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B56',$add);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B55')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

    //Completed By
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B66:M66');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B67:C67');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('D67:G67');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('H67:I67');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J67:M67');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B68:C68');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('D68:G68');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('H68:M68');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B69:M70');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B66','COMPLETED BY');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B67','Name:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('D67',$name);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('H67','Title:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('J67',$title);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B68','Date:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('BD68',$date);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B66')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');  
    $objWriter->save('Senior Managers Site Tour.xls');

    //Send Email

    require("PHP/class.phpmailer.php");
    require("PHP/class.smtp.php");

    $path1 = "Senior Managers Site Tour.xls"; 
    $path2 = "UPLOADS/Image Attachment.jpg"; 


    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.sulmaxmarketing.com";

    $mail->From = "matt@sulmaxcp.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Murphy's Online Documentation System";
    $mail->AddAddress("sulmaxcp@gmail.com");

    $mail->Subject = "Senior Managers Site Tour";
    $mail->Body = "You've just recieved an document via the Murphys Senior Managers Site Tour website.\nYour document is in the attachments";
    $mail->AddAttachment($path1);
    $mail->AddAttachment($path2);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
    header("Location: Review_DocumentFailedToSend.php");
    } else {
    header("Location: Review_DocumentSent.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: try this [https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/146](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/146)

Comment: So opened up the worksheet.php and removed the sheetNameExists method and sure enough the error was gone and a new one occurred. This time it was "Call to undefined method PHPExcel::getCalculationEngine() in /home3/hutch/public_html/sulmaxcp.com/PHP/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php on line 842"

Comment: You should download the latest library again and use code a peer the library documentation;